# Show a multiple choice form in a "Create" : Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

well i'm working with ASP MVC crud operations with generated forms with Entity Framework, but not all fields are the ones that i need to be shown. I mean, for example, a Create operation for the model Town (name, country).

- first, country field is a reference on the table Country (i must maybe display a combobox filled with all countries on the database)
- second, a many-to-many relationship with Transport (car, bus, train) and Town : here a town can have many transports and a transport can be found in many touns. here is may question : Can i display here a multiple choice (a checkbox list) with all transports that exists in the database?

i really need help please, maybe some questions are a little bit similar to my request but i made a search but i found nothing that may help me. 
Thank You All ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bring county and transport data into your view. what i guess from your answer is that you are sending your entity directly to your view. you should rather create a viewmodel including enumeration of countries and transports and then on your view you can use

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryID", "countryName"))%>
```

plz look at this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333305/viewmodel-with-selectlist-binding-in-asp-net-mvc2) to find more about selectlist binding with viewmodels

Comment: well, in my View page Create.aspx, i changed this : 

Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GuidigoStudioAlpha.Models.ModelObjects> 

and in the ModelObjects class i have this : 
public Town Town { get; set; } 
public Country Country { get; set; } 
public Transport Transport { get; set; } 

i did this to be able to show information coming from more than one model in the view... what should i do next? 
PS : the original request for showing all countries or transports is not a simple select *, but with a WHERE condition!

Comment: @saif what are you using for data access: any ORM like Linq to sql or ADO.NET? and plz to post code, edit your question rather than putting it in comments

Comment: @mumammad : this is my first post on this forum so i'm sorry :) then i'm working with ADO.NET Entity Data Model